# parse SDK objective c - retrieving CreatedAt column

Tags: objective-c, pfquery, parse-framework

Im trying to get the column "createdAt" for parse objects but when Im retrieving all the object, none of them include it.

this is my code for getting all the objects i need:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name = '%@'", @"bob"]];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"People" predicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"%@", [query findObjects]);
```

the column is not inside any object...

the idea is to show only by day and month when the user signed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as i found out you just cannot get the createdAt column in parse but you can get the objects sorted in date order by createAt column

link here

> https://parse.com/questions/query-object-then-sort-returned-data